# Is a corner roller or corner pad a good tool to use to cut into corners when painting?

Tags: painting

We are preparing to paint some walls, and want to know if a corner roller or a corner pad are good tools to use for cutting in the corners.  We are hesitant to cut in with a brush since it leaves a different 'texture' than the 9" roller we will use for the rest of the wall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried a bunch of tools for cutting in corners/edges (the worst part of the job, IMO), and always end up going back to using a paintbrush.  There's not enough of a texture difference to notice it unless you have your face ON the wall (once it's dry), and it's much easier to deal with.

My family helps each other with painting, and my sister has textured walls. In that case we did use foam rollers to cut in, just for the better coverage in the texture. As long as you have plain, flat, drywall, brushes are the way to go IMO.

Comment: I agree with the brush idea for cutting in. Then it is not hard at all to bring the 9" roller right up near the corners and edges so only a very small margin of the brushed corner is there. After drying it is good as gone.